# determine Maclaurin series for function $(1+z)e^{-z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

I need prove that Maclaurin series of

$$ (1+z)\cdot {e^{-z}} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)z^{n}}} {n!}$$

I tried divide the function $$ (1+z)\cdot{e^{-z}} = {e^{-z}} + z{e^{-z}}$$
But my result is equal to 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n}z^{n}}} {n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n}z^{n+1}}} {n!}$

Can anyone give a tip on how to get the desired result?

Comment: Try to compute the sums of the series you got term by term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n}z^{n}}} {n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n}z^{n+1}}} {n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n}z^{n}}} {n!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n-1}z^{n}}} {(n-1)!} \\&= 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)z^{n}}} {n!} \\ &=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)z^{n}}} {n!} 
\end{aligned}
$$